# $W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is the same as $C^{0,1}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $f\in (C_c(\mathbb{R}))^*$ be a distribution. Show that $f\in C^{0,1}(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, and the distributional derivative $f'$ of $f$ also lies in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Here $C^{0,1}(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of continuous functions with bounded $C^{0,1}(\mathbb{R})$-norm defined by
$$\|f\|_{C^{0,1}(\mathbb{R})}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|+\sup_{x,y\in\mathbb{R}:x\neq y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}.$$

I can prove that if $f\in C^{0,1}(\mathbb{R})$, then $f$ and $f'$ lie in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, but I don't know how to prove the reverse. Now suppose that $f$ and $f'$ (in the distributional sense) lies in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, How to show that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous almost everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

If $f\in W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R)$, then $f'\in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$, now observe that $f$ is continuous by Morrey's inequality. Then
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant\int_y^x |f'(t)|\,\mathrm dt
$$
Does that help you establishing the Lipschitz condition?

Comment: How to prove that $f$ is continuous? I think we can only prove that $f$ is  continuous almost everywhere since modifying  $f$ on a null doesn't change the condition.

Comment: You can choose a continuous representative of your equivalence class. This is the content of Morrey's inequality. That's how I mean it. Otherwise the statement you'd like to prove is wrong anyway because you can add as many discontinuities as you like for a fixed choice of a representative in a class in $ W^{1,\infty}$...